# Error in compiling a program that uses gmp

Tags: c++, c, gmp, mpfr

A friend sent me a somewhat complex code that uses gmpfr, which uses gmp and mpfr. When trying to link gmp I get the following error:

```
/tmp/cc44K2j2.o: In function `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Integer const&)':
callEnumPar.cpp:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __mpz_struct const*)'
/tmp/cc44K2j2.o: In function `operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Integer&)':
callEnumPar.cpp:(.text+0x492): undefined reference to `operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __mpz_struct*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm compiling it this way:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp libgmpfrxx.a -I $(GMP)/include -L $(GMP)/lib/ -lgmp -lgmpxx -I $(MPFR)/include -L $(MPFR)/lib -lmpfr  $(CFLAGS)
```

I also already tried it with the static library of gmp:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp libgmpfrxx.a -I $(GMP)/include $(GMP)/lib/libgmp.a  -I $(MPFR)/include -L $(MPFR)/lib -lmpfr  $(CFLAGS)
```

I'm using gcc 4.6.1 on an Ubuntu 11.10.

Does anyone have a clue of where the problem could lie?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you should list libraries in this order: `-lmpfr -lgmpxx -lgmp`, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Your second try cannot work, you forgot to link with gmpxx, which is the library that contains those 2 symbols.

Comment: @MarcGlisse When changing the order of the libraries it compiles, but then I get this error:

error while loading shared libraries: libgmpxx.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

But when I check the directory where gmp is installed, the file is there.